# sequence of p-harmonic functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Consider $\Omega$ a bounded open set in $R^n$  with $ \partial \Omega$  smooth and $u_n \in C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega)$ a bounded sequence in $C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega)$.

Suppose that each $u_n$ is p - harmonic (in the weak sense)  .  the proof of the theorem that i am studying says : "Then  we can easily show that on  every compact of subset of $\Omega $ , $u_n$ converges   in $C^{1,\alpha} $ norm to a p- harmonic function (in the weak sense) $u$". (*)

I believe that is a subsequence and not the sequence.

My ideas : the inclusion $C^{1,\alpha} \subset C^{0}$ is compact, then exists a funtion $u$ in $C^{0}$ where $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $C^{0}$  . I believe that this the that i am searching...

Someone can help me to prove the affirmation in $(*)$ ?. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Where is this proof?

Comment: no. its form a text that i am studying  . the text it's not published

Comment: I don't understand the convergence; you've said that the sequence converges in $C^{1,\alpha}$ in every compact subset $\Omega$ and then you write: (in the weak sense). What this mean?

Comment: i wanted to mean "p harmonic in the weak sense"

Comment: Just one more question: what is the definiton of weak $p$-harmonic

Comment: Are you sure that the convergence of the sequence is in $C^{1,\alpha}$?. The author says what space $u$ belongs?

Comment: Yes, it is a subsequence. Sometimes the original sequence is replaced by the subsequence for convenience. We could say that it is an abuse of notation.

Comment: u is $p - harmonic$ in the weak sense in $\Omega$ if $ \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u |^{p-2}    \nabla u \nabla \phi = 0$ , $\forall \ \phi \in W^{1,p}_{0} (\Omega)$

Comment: @Tomás , the autor says that $u \in C^{1,\alpha}$

Comment: If $u$ is any weak $p$-harmonic function, then $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: If the $\partial \Omega$ $\in C^{\infty}$ and $\Omega$ is bounded  , yes . Moreover $u \in C^{1,\alpha} (\overline{\Omega})$ (by a theorem of regularity) . Consider $\partial \Omega$ is smooth and bounded

Comment: If $\partial\Omega\in C^{\infty}$, can we assume that $u_n\in C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: @Tomás        yes , you can assume

Comment: Leandro take a look in theorem 3.78 of Heinonen. He prove the same resut without assuming regularity.

Comment: Eu vi o resultado que vc falou aqui no livro. eu nao conhecia tal resultado. Muito obrigado !!!

Comment: De nada, a prova que eu ia dar usava a regularidade. A dele é mais geral.